# Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet

Since yesterday I can't connect to my Android's WiFi anymore.

To understand the problem better, I set NetworkManager's monitor log level to "DEBUG" and used the CLI. The error appears after 45 seconds:

```
# nmcli d wifi connect nico password mypass
Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

Meanwhile via `nmcli monitor`:

```
nico: connection profile created
wlp3s0: connecting (prepare)
wlp3s0: using connection 'nico'
NeworkManager is now in the 'connecting' state
wlp3s0: connecting (need authentication)
nico: connection profile changed
wlp3s0: connecting (prepare)
wlp3s0: connecting (configuring)
nico: connection profile changed
wlp3s0: connecting (getting IP configuration)
wlp3s0: connection failed
```

What is going wrong? How to investigate the problem further and hopefully solve it?

- My Android is connected to the Internet (typing from it right now).
- No luck with Bluetooth nor with USB cable tethering either.
- On the opposite, I can connect to my company's WiFi with no problem.

Comment: Did you have any luck in solving this?

Answer (score 3):

Install `dnsmasq` and then try it again:

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me!